# Are Weinberg's soft theorems relevant when making predictions about collider physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, renormalization, quantum-gravity

In a [seminal paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.140.B516), Weinberg has shown that one can relate a $n \to m$ scattering amplitude to the $n \to m + k$ scattering amplitude that involves the same particle content plus $k$ additional outgoing soft photons or gravitons. "Soft" particles are particles with energy below a certain infrared cutoff, that in principle cannot be detected by a collider experiment's detectors due to being too faint in energy.

My question is whether the effect of soft particles is taken into account when one performs the calculations for cross sections, for example, relating to collider physics experiments. In particular, I'm interested in whether the soft graviton theorem plays a relevant role for the Standard Model predictions to match the experimental data.

Comment: I doubt it has any relevance in scattering experiments since those only involve inclusive cross-sections (The soft-graviton theorem is theoretically relevant here as it is needed to prove that inclusive cross-sections are IR finite). However, there are memory experiments for which the soft theorems are relevant.

Comment: From the abstract of [SAGEX review: Amplitudes and collider physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.13023): … *we explain how the study of (next-to-)soft radiation is directly relevant to increasing theoretical precision for key processes at the LHC and related experiments* …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Gravitons* have never been observed, much less *graviton scattering*, so the graviton soft theorem is not relevant for particle physics experiments.

The graviton soft theorem has been shown to be related to the gravitational-wave memory effect, which is a non-linear effect that applies to classical gravitational waves. Gravitational wave detectors like LIGO and Virgo search for the memory effect, although as far as I know it has not been detected to date. (Because it is hard to detect, not because there are serious reasons to think it isn't there).

In terms of experimental tests of the soft *photon* theorem, it looks like there is at least a proposal to use a detector at the LHC to use the soft photon theorem to study QCD phenomena: https://indico.gsi.de/event/11946/contributions/50402/attachments/34543/45390/2021_RRTF_Low.pdf. However, I've always understood the main point of the theorem to be more theoretical, by constraining the types of singularities that have to occur in S-matrix elements, and understanding the soft limit is necessary to see how to deal with infrared divergences.